# How to import constant from frontend side of Node app and use it at backend side, in POST route

Tags: javascript, node.js

Let's say I have some frontend code saved in "public/js/frontend.js":

```
// some jquery...
$(function() {
    // ...
});

//...

const names = ['abc123', 'qwe456', 'zxc789']
const rand = names[Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length)];
document.getElementById("captcha").src=`/img/captcha_${rand}.jpg`;
```

and I have some backend code saved here: "controllers/registration.js"

```
post: async (req, res, next) => {

    // ...

    if (valid.value.captcha_input !== 'rand') {

        // do something, i.e.
        req.flash('captcha_wrong', 'Please enter the characters you see to continue.');
        res.redirect('/registration');
        return;

    }
}
```

As you can see I need to export "rand" constant from "frondend.js" file and import it to "registration.js" file. The reason is I want to compare randomly picked value (from "names" array) with value entered by user, something like that:

[image]

The comparison will take place when user will click "submitt" button.

**What I've tried so far:**

1.

```
import { rand } from '../public/js/frontend';
```

in "registration.js", right after "npm start" command, gives me this in Terminal:

```
import { rand } from '../public/js/frontend';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

2.

```
const { rand } = require('../public/js/frontend');
```

also in "registration.js", right after I click "submitt" button, gives me this in Browser:

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

3.

```
module.exports = rand;
```

in "frontend.js" gives me the same as 2.

4.

```
localStorage.setItem('rand', rand);
```

in "frontend.js" seems to work properly (with every reload of "http://localhost:5000/registration") Local Storage in Browser is updated), but

```
rand = localStorage.getItem('rand');
```

in "registration.js", right after I click "submitt" button, gives me this in Browser:

```
ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined
```

**In summary**, I do not know how to import "rand" constant from "frontend.js" without importing "$" - jQuery code I need for something else. And, I can not use Local Storage in backend side ("registration.js").

I will appreciate any useful hint. Thanks!

Comment: why don't you pass it as a parameter in post via ajax call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, value from your variable is dynamically defined on the browser, server can't know its value without your browser sending it.

There are two ways to share value between browser and server.

1. Sharing file

In this case value must not be dynamically generated. You can create file inside your public folder that you import into your browser JS code using either `<script>` tag or using bundler solution such as Webpack. Then you will be also able to require that file inside Node.js server code as well by using `global.require` function. Note: This case works only if value is static. (predefined)

2. AJAX

This is the case which fits your needs. In this case you can generate value on the client and use it on the server. Basically generate value and send HTTP request to your server which should handle request and use/store value accordingly. This allows you to use dynamic values generated in  browser accessed by server.

**As for your errors:**

Your first error related to import keyword is because you do not use bundler (such as webpack) or `type="module"` property on your script tag (see here about that: https://jaketrent.com/post/import-js-module-without-dot-dot-slash/) but I would recommend using webpack due to browser compatibility.

Your browser probably knows `$` is jQuery due to global import via script tag inside your html file. But on the server it doesn't exist or browser JS file that lives inside other html file where `$` is not globally accessible throws this error.

`global.localStorage` is browser only object which doesn't exist inside Node.js, you can't use it on your server, use AJAX instead.

Basically these two JavaScript files you shared above live on different environments, one lives inside user's browser and other lives on your hosting server. To make them communicate use AJAX.